# Capture Apache httpclient transmitted data as part of TCP connections

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, http-monitor

In my application, I have used apache HttpClient. Now I would like to monitor the request and response from the capture data transmitted by the httpclient. Is it possible to know which ports are opened by the HttpClient. I am using Linux, so can I use netstat to see which ports are open by my java application process?

Answer (score 0):

You can get detailed info about connection management by turning on context logging as described [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html)